# Access to BIM 360 Hubs

Tags: autodesk-forge

We are integrating with BIM 360 using the forge api. We would like to be able to return all hubs, not just the team hubs. Ex: Docs, Glue, Field...

This has been asked before, but the question is a year old now, so thought I would open a new question to see if we could get an update.

I have looked at the blog post on accessing Docs, but still looking for when a full integration may be expected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you wrote, you probably seen this post: 
https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2017/08/18/no-custom-integrations-tab/
to activate an API access to Docs with less than 100 users, you will need to request it to activate. (I agree, it will be less confusing if we do not need to go through this. I will raise it to the product team.)

For Glue and Field - Glue and Field are in a transitional phase. Currently, we have a "classic" Glue and new generation Glue, which is called Model Coordination. Field, we have Field Management. Both are built on top of Docs and they are in preview now. If you have a Glue or Field license, you should see a option to choose new or classic when you create a project in Account Admin. Classic ones aren't built with Forge, but new ones are. With new ones, it will be the same as Docs. So it's coming little by little.